# Unable to view dataframe after using dfidx

Tags: r, dataframe, mlogit

I am learning how to use mlogit package. These are some lines that appear as an example in a vignette of the package:

```
data("Heating", package = "mlogit")
H <- dfidx(Heating, choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
```

However, when I want to view df H, I keep getting the same error: *r error 4 (R code execution error)*

This is the error that appears in the console:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, start:min(NROW(x), start + len)) :
> undefined columns selected

The funny thing is that if a restart R, I can view the df. It seems that the problem is created when I want to use the package mlogit.

Any hint what could be going on?

Comment: have you loaded the package i.e. `library(mlogit)`

Comment: Yes, I have. I get the error when I try to view the df after applying dfidx.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error though

Comment: Could it be some kind of incompatibility with the dfidx/mlogit packages? I can view the df when I restart R but I cannot view it when I re-upload either package.

Comment: I used `packageVersion("dfidx")
[1] ‘0.0.4’
> packageVersion("mlogit")
[1] ‘1.1.1’`

Comment: When I load mlogit I get the following warning:

> library("mlogit")
Loading required package: dfidx

Attaching package: ‘dfidx’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

Could that explain the problem?

Comment: that is a friendly message stating the masked function.  There is nothing wrong in that